# some files show extensions while others don't (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: macos

The issue is very minor but I'm OCD with these things. I love consistency.

The first screenshot was taken from an ls output. As you can see all the files have an .xlsx extension.

[image: ls output]

The second screenshot was taken using finder. As you can see, one file shows the extension while the rest don't.

[image]

I don't want to change the finder setting where all extensions are shown.

Any ideas what could be the issue? thanks

Comment: When you Get Info on the file, is hide extension checked on?

Comment: Maybe Excel is set to hide file extensions when saving files.  If you want to have all the `.xlsx` extensions show for those files, then in Terminal, change directory to the location of the `.xlsx` files and use the following command to have all the `.xlsx` extensions for those files show in Finder: `for f in *.xlsx; do xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo "$f"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Recent builds of Office applications are hiding file extensions by default, and have removed the save UI feature that allows you to override this. Your options are to either continue manually changing files to show extensions, or live with the inconsistency. Personally I agree with you, and would rather have the extensions shown for specific file types, but it appears that whether the save UI allows you to show extensions is up to the application authors. You have to complain to Microsoft on this one.